# How to efficiently pipe data of HTTP GET to HTTP PUT in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, http, pipeline

I would like to asynchronously download data and then upload it again using .NET. Ideally this should work in .NET and .NET Core as I need to use this in PowerShell 5 and 6 in the end.

I searched for a while but couldn't really find a good example, but a few hints that PushStreamContent could be the right way. Unfortunately PushStreamContent is only available via ASP.NET and I didn't find a way to use it with ASP.NET Core, but I managed to copy the relevant parts from GitHub and make it work without external dependencies in a .NET Core program.

This is how I ended up using a C# example with .NET Core 2.2 ([see this Fiddle for full code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NdBmAk)):

```
private async Task pipeGetToPut()
{
    System.Net.Http.HttpClient downloadHttpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
    System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage getRequest = 
        new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage(
            System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get, 
            new System.Uri(downloadUri));
    System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage getResponseMessage = 
        await downloadHttpClient.SendAsync(
            getRequest, 
            System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
    getResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    System.Net.Http.HttpClient uploadHttpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
    HttpRequestMessage putRequest = 
        new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, new System.Uri(uploadUri));
    putRequest.Content = 
        new PushStreamContent(async (stream, httpContent, transportContext) =>
        {
            Task copyTask = getResponseMessage.Content.CopyToAsync(stream);
            await copyTask;
            stream.Dispose();
        });
    putRequest.Content.Headers.ContentLength = 
        getResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentLength;
    uploadHttpClient.Timeout = 
        new TimeSpan(
            0, 
            0, 
            Math.Max(
              (Int32)(getResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentLength / (60 * 1024)), 
              (Int32)60));

    System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage putResponseMessage = 
        await uploadHttpClient.SendAsync(putRequest);
    putResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}
```

- Is PushStreamContent the right way to go?
- Is there a better way to pipe HTTP GET Stream to HTTP PUT stream?

Comment: I deleted my answer after studying your code a little more diligently. Looks fine to me.

Comment: This code is hardly readable with all the namespaces. Clean up your example to get better traction on your question.

Comment: I could have separated the code, but I rather would like to get rid of all classes related to PushStreamContent and use an official implementation. As mentioned in the question, I couldn’t find an implementation of PushStreamContent for .NET Core and would be glad for suggestions where to get one!

Comment: I have cleaned up the code in the Fiddle and removed all dependencies which are not really necessary. Any hints for improvements very much welcome!